# Speed up web requests by making multiple at once?

Tags: python, multithreading, http, request, lxml

Will running multiple processes that all make HTTP requests be notably faster than one?

I'm parsing about a million urls using `lxml.html.parse`

At first, I ran a Python process that simply looped through the urls and called `lxml.html.parse(myUrl)` on each, and waited for the rest of the method to deal with the data before doing so again. This way, I was able to process on the order of `10000` urls/hour.

I imagined that if I ran a few identical processes (dealing with different sets of urls), I would speed up the rate at which I could fetch these urls. Surprisingly, (to me at least), I measured about `10400` urls/hour this time, which isn't notably better, considering I'm sure both were fluctuating dramatically.

**My question is: why isn't running three of these processes much faster than one?**

I know for a fact that my requests aren't meaningfully affecting their target in any way, so I don't think it's them. Do I not have enough bandwidth to make these extra processes worthwhile? If not, how can I measure this? Am I totally misunderstanding how my MacBook is running these processes? (I'm assuming on different cores concurrent threads, or something roughly equivalent to that.) Something else entirely?

(Apologies if I mangled any web terminology -- I'm new to this kind of stuff. Corrections are appreciated.)

Note: I imagine that running these processes on three different servers would probably be about 3x as fast. (That correct?) I'm not interested in that -- worst case, 10000/hour is sufficient for my purposes.

Edit: from speedtest.net (twice):

```
With 3 running:
Ping: 29 ms (25 ms)
Download speed: 6.63 mbps (7.47 mbps)
Upload speed: 3.02 mbps (3.32 mbps)

With all paused:
Ping: 26 ms (28 ms)
Download speed: 9.32 mbps (8.82 mbps)
Upload speed: 5.15 mbps (6.56 mbps)
```

Comment: What's your network connection speed? this plays a hughe factor in stateful connections (Open, request, wait, get data, close). It also depends on **how** you run the "separate" processes, since Python itself is single-core-threaded and unless you spawn your threads in the correct way you'll just be "software threading" your stuff.

Comment: Correct, running the same script on 3 different machines on three different connections would be 3 times as fast.

Comment: @Torxed see my edit. I'm running my separate processes in separate terminal windows. I don't know much about Python threading - I could look into it, but I assumed that "software threading" would be good enough.

Comment: software threading would be good enough in your situation, and starting 3 different processes in 3 different consoles is perfectly fine :) You're issue is your network bandwidth coupled with your latency on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have roughly `7mbit/s` (1MB/s counting high).
If you get `2.888 pages per second` (10'400 pages per hour). I'd say you're maxing out your connection speed (especially if you're running ADSL or WiFi, you're hammering with TCP connection handshakes for sure).

You're downloading a page roughly containing `354kB` of data in each of your processes, which isn't half bad considering that's close the the limit of your bandwidth.

Take in account for TCP headers and all that happens when you actually establish a connection (SYN, ACK.. etc) You're up in a descent speed tbh.

**Note:** This is just to take in account the download rate which is much higher than your upload speed which is also important considering that's what actually transmits your connection request, headers to the web server etc. And i know most 3G modems and ADSL lines claim to be "full duplex", they really aren't (especially ADSL). You'll never perform full speed in both direction despite what your ISP tells you. If you want to achieve such tasks you need to switch to fiber optics.

Ps. I assume you understand the basic difference between mega-**bit** and mega-**byte**.

Comment: Yup, wifi. Thanks for the info. And my computer doesn't even have an ethernet jack! Before I accept: if I were able to raise my connection speed, would running multiple processes as described eventually make a difference?

Comment: And yes, I understand the difference between a mega-bit and mega-byte.

Comment: @rogaos Yes it would, theoretically. It all boils down to your connection speed and how fast your ISP serves the SYN/ACK requests and the routing of your headers afterwards. You can optemize the headers etc and request GZipped data from the server, and hopefully it will honor your request making the contents of the website 1/3 of its original size making it quicker to transport back to your machine. I'd say look into that and improve your overall network connection speed for these kinds of tests (fiber or at least try to ditch 3G modems and wifi's for these kind of things)

Comment: @rogaos Another good idea for future projects is to get a network speed monitor of any kind, and see what you're using up when running scripts like these (knowing your maximum connection speed, that will show you if it's a script issue or network issue) :) Good luck!

Comment: thanks, really helpful and thorough. You gave me a lot to research, too, which is always a good sign.